# pimcore workflow management - disabling Save and publish

Tags: pimcore

In pimcore I tried implementing the workflow management for objects. Workflow is working fine. But, save and publish button are still appearing, how can I remove these features if workflow is enabled.   1. Disabling Save, publish, unpublish and delete to the user if workflow is enabled.   2. Removing same options (save, publish, unpublish and delete) on right clicking the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable buttons you have to overwrite pimcore object.js(pimcore/static6/js/pimcore/object/object.js) and tree.js(pimcore/static6/js/pimcore/object/tree.js). 
First create plugin. Then create object.js in static(Remember to add js paths to plugin.xml) and add code:

```
pimcore.registerNS("pimcore.object.object");

pimcore.object.object = Class.create(pimcore.object.object, {

getLayoutToolbar : function () {

    if (!this.toolbar) {

        var buttons = [];

        this.toolbarButtons = {};

        this.toolbarButtons.save = new Ext.SplitButton({
            text: t('save'),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_save",
            scale: "medium",
            handler: this.save.bind(this, "unpublish"),
            menu:[{
                text: t('save_close'),
                iconCls: "pimcore_icon_save",
                handler: this.unpublishClose.bind(this)
            }]
        });

        this.toolbarButtons.publish = new Ext.SplitButton({
            text: t('save_and_publish'),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_publish",
            scale: "medium",
            handler: this.publish.bind(this),
            menu: [{
                text: t('save_pubish_close'),
                iconCls: "pimcore_icon_save",
                handler: this.publishClose.bind(this)
            },
                {
                    text: t('save_only_new_version'),
                    iconCls: "pimcore_icon_save",
                    handler: this.save.bind(this, "version")
                },
                {
                    text: t('save_only_scheduled_tasks'),
                    iconCls: "pimcore_icon_save",
                    handler: this.save.bind(this, "scheduler","scheduler")
                }
            ]
        });

        this.toolbarButtons.unpublish = new Ext.Button({
            text: t('unpublish'),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_unpublish",
            scale: "medium",
            handler: this.unpublish.bind(this)
        });

        this.toolbarButtons.remove = new Ext.Button({
            tooltip: t("delete"),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_delete",
            scale: "medium",
            handler: this.remove.bind(this)
        });

        this.toolbarButtons.rename = new Ext.Button({
            tooltip: t('rename'),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_key pimcore_icon_overlay_go",
            scale: "medium",
            handler: function () {
                var options = {
                    elementType: "object",
                    elementSubType: this.data.general.o_type,
                    id: this.id,
                    default: this.data.general.o_key
                };
                pimcore.elementservice.editElementKey(options);
            }.bind(this)
        });






        //This code is for save&publish buttons
        if (this.isAllowed("save")) {
            buttons.push(this.toolbarButtons.save);
        }
        if (this.isAllowed("publish")) {
            buttons.push(this.toolbarButtons.publish);
        }
        if (this.isAllowed("unpublish") && !this.data.general.o_locked) {
            buttons.push(this.toolbarButtons.unpublish);
        }






        buttons.push("-");

        if(this.isAllowed("delete") && !this.data.general.o_locked) {
            buttons.push(this.toolbarButtons.remove);
        }
        if(this.isAllowed("rename") && !this.data.general.o_locked) {
            buttons.push(this.toolbarButtons.rename);
        }

        var reloadConfig = {
            xtype: "splitbutton",
            tooltip: t('reload'),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_reload",
            scale: "medium",
            handler: this.reload.bind(this, this.data.currentLayoutId)
        };

        if (this.data["validLayouts"] && this.data.validLayouts.length > 1) {
            var menu = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < this.data.validLayouts.length; i++) {
                var menuLabel = ts(this.data.validLayouts[i].name);
                if (Number(this.data.currentLayoutId) == this.data.validLayouts[i].id) {
                    menuLabel = "<b>" + menuLabel + "</b>";
                }
                menu.push({
                    text: menuLabel,
                    iconCls: "pimcore_icon_reload",
                    handler: this.reload.bind(this, this.data.validLayouts[i].id)
                });
            }
            reloadConfig.menu = menu;
        }

        buttons.push(reloadConfig);

        if (pimcore.elementservice.showLocateInTreeButton("object")) {
            if (this.data.general.o_type != "variant" || this.data.general.showVariants) {
                buttons.push({
                    tooltip: t('show_in_tree'),
                    iconCls: "pimcore_icon_show_in_tree",
                    scale: "medium",
                    handler: this.selectInTree.bind(this, this.data.general.o_type)
                });
            }
        }

        buttons.push({
            tooltip: t("show_metainfo"),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_info",
            scale: "medium",
            handler: this.showMetaInfo.bind(this)
        });

        buttons.push("-");
        buttons.push({
            xtype: 'tbtext',
            text: t("id") + " " + this.data.general.o_id,
            scale: "medium"
        });

        buttons.push("-");
        buttons.push({
            xtype: 'tbtext',
            text: ts(this.data.general.o_className),
            scale: "medium"
        });

        // version notification
        this.newerVersionNotification = new Ext.Toolbar.TextItem({
            xtype: 'tbtext',
            text: '&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/pimcore/static6/img/flat-color-icons/medium_priority.svg" style="height: 16px;" align="absbottom" />&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                + t("this_is_a_newer_not_published_version"),
            scale: "medium",
            hidden: true
        });

        buttons.push(this.newerVersionNotification);

        //workflow management
        pimcore.elementservice.integrateWorkflowManagement('object', this.id, this, buttons);

        // check for newer version than the published
        if (this.data.versions.length > 0) {
            if (this.data.general.o_modificationDate < this.data.versions[0].date) {
                this.newerVersionNotification.show();
            }
        }

        this.toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({
            id: "object_toolbar_" + this.id,
            region: "north",
            border: false,
            cls: "main-toolbar",
            items: buttons,
            overflowHandler: 'scroller'
        });

        this.toolbar.on("afterrender", function () {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                if (!this.data.general.o_published) {
                    this.toolbarButtons.unpublish.hide();
                } else if (this.isAllowed("publish")) {
                    this.toolbarButtons.save.hide();
                }
            }.bind(this), 500);
        }.bind(this));
    }

    return this.toolbar;
}
});
```

You have to do the same with tree.js:

```
pimcore.object.tree = Class.create({
onTreeNodeContextmenu: function (tree, record, item, index, e, eOpts ) {
    e.stopEvent();

    tree.select();

    var menu = new Ext.menu.Menu();

    var perspectiveCfg = this.perspectiveCfg;

    var object_types = pimcore.globalmanager.get("object_types_store_create");

    var objectMenu = {
        objects: [],
        importer: [],
        ref: this
    };

    var groups = {
        importer: {},
        objects: {}
    };

    var tmpMenuEntry;
    var tmpMenuEntryImport;
    var $this = this;

    object_types.each(function (classRecord) {

        if ($this.config.allowedClasses && !in_array(classRecord.get("id"), $this.config.allowedClasses)) {
            return;
        }

        tmpMenuEntry = {
            text: classRecord.get("translatedText"),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_object pimcore_icon_overlay_add",
            handler: $this.addObject.bind($this, classRecord.get("id"), classRecord.get("text"), tree, record)
        };

        // add special icon
        if (classRecord.get("icon") != "/pimcore/static6/img/flat-color-icons/timeline.svg") {
            tmpMenuEntry.icon = classRecord.get("icon");
            tmpMenuEntry.iconCls = "";
        }

        tmpMenuEntryImport = {
            text: classRecord.get("translatedText"),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_object pimcore_icon_overlay_add",
            handler: $this.importObjects.bind($this, classRecord.get("id"), classRecord.get("text"), tree, record)
        };

        // add special icon
        if (classRecord.get("icon") != "/pimcore/static6/img/flat-color-icons/timeline.svg") {
            tmpMenuEntryImport.icon = classRecord.get("icon");
            tmpMenuEntryImport.iconCls = "";
        }


        // check if the class is within a group
        if(classRecord.get("group")) {
            if(!groups["objects"][classRecord.get("group")]) {
                groups["objects"][classRecord.get("group")] = {
                    text: classRecord.get("group"),
                    iconCls: "pimcore_icon_folder",
                    hideOnClick: false,
                    menu: {
                        items: []
                    }
                };
                groups["importer"][classRecord.get("group")] = {
                    text: classRecord.get("group"),
                    iconCls: "pimcore_icon_folder",
                    hideOnClick: false,
                    menu: {
                        items: []
                    }
                };
                objectMenu["objects"].push(groups["objects"][classRecord.get("group")]);
                objectMenu["importer"].push(groups["importer"][classRecord.get("group")]);
            }

            groups["objects"][classRecord.get("group")]["menu"]["items"].push(tmpMenuEntry);
            groups["importer"][classRecord.get("group")]["menu"]["items"].push(tmpMenuEntryImport);
        } else {
            objectMenu["objects"].push(tmpMenuEntry);
            objectMenu["importer"].push(tmpMenuEntryImport);
        }
    });


    var isVariant = record.data.type == "variant";

    if (record.data.permissions.create) {
        if (!isVariant) {
            if (perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.add")) {
                menu.add(new Ext.menu.Item({
                    text: t('add_object'),
                    iconCls: "pimcore_icon_object pimcore_icon_overlay_add",
                    hideOnClick: false,
                    menu: objectMenu.objects
                }));
            }
        }

        if (record.data.allowVariants && perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.add")) {
            menu.add(new Ext.menu.Item({
                text: t("add_variant"),
                iconCls: "pimcore_icon_variant",
                handler: this.createVariant.bind(this, tree, record)
            }));
        }

        if (!isVariant) {

            if (perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.addFolder")) {
                menu.add(new Ext.menu.Item({
                    text: t('add_folder'),
                    iconCls: "pimcore_icon_folder pimcore_icon_overlay_add",
                    handler: this.addFolder.bind(this, tree, record)
                }));
            }

            if (perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.importCsv")) {
                menu.add({
                    text: t('import_csv'),
                    hideOnClick: false,
                    iconCls: "pimcore_icon_object pimcore_icon_overlay_upload",
                    menu: objectMenu.importer
                });
            }

            menu.add("-");

            //paste
            var pasteMenu = [];

            if (perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.paste")) {
                if (pimcore.cachedObjectId && record.data.permissions.create) {
                    pasteMenu.push({
                        text: t("paste_recursive_as_childs"),
                        iconCls: "pimcore_icon_paste",
                        handler: this.pasteInfo.bind(this, tree, record, "recursive")
                    });
                    pasteMenu.push({
                        text: t("paste_recursive_updating_references"),
                        iconCls: "pimcore_icon_paste",
                        handler: this.pasteInfo.bind(this, tree, record, "recursive-update-references")
                    });
                    pasteMenu.push({
                        text: t("paste_as_child"),
                        iconCls: "pimcore_icon_paste",
                        handler: this.pasteInfo.bind(this, tree, record, "child")
                    });


                    if (record.data.type != "folder") {
                        pasteMenu.push({
                            text: t("paste_contents"),
                            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_paste",
                            handler: this.pasteInfo.bind(this, tree, record, "replace")
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!isVariant) {
                if (pimcore.cutObject && record.data.permissions.create) {
                    pasteMenu.push({
                        text: t("paste_cut_element"),
                        iconCls: "pimcore_icon_paste",
                        handler: function () {
                            this.pasteCutObject(pimcore.cutObject,
                                pimcore.cutObjectParentNode, record, this.tree);
                            pimcore.cutObjectParentNode = null;
                            pimcore.cutObject = null;
                        }.bind(this)
                    });
                }

                if (pasteMenu.length > 0) {
                    menu.add(new Ext.menu.Item({
                        text: t('paste'),
                        iconCls: "pimcore_icon_paste",
                        hideOnClick: false,
                        menu: pasteMenu
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isVariant) {
        if (record.data.id != 1 && record.data.permissions.view && perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.copy")) {
            menu.add(new Ext.menu.Item({
                text: t('copy'),
                iconCls: "pimcore_icon_copy",
                handler: this.copy.bind(this, tree, record)
            }));
        }

        //cut
        if (record.data.id != 1 && !record.data.locked && record.data.permissions.rename && perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.cut")) {
            menu.add(new Ext.menu.Item({
                text: t('cut'),
                iconCls: "pimcore_icon_cut",
                handler: this.cut.bind(this, tree, record)
            }));
        }
    }

    //publish
    if (record.data.type != "folder" && !record.data.locked) {
        if (record.data.published && record.data.permissions.unpublish && perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.unpublish")) {
            menu.add(new Ext.menu.Item({
                text: t('unpublish'),
                iconCls: "pimcore_icon_unpublish",
                handler: this.publishObject.bind(this, tree, record, 'unpublish')
            }));
        } else if (!record.data.published && record.data.permissions.publish && perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.publish")) {
            menu.add(new Ext.menu.Item({
                text: t('publish'),
                iconCls: "pimcore_icon_publish",
                handler: this.publishObject.bind(this, tree, record, 'publish')
            }));
        }
    }


    if (record.data.permissions["delete"] && record.data.id != 1 && !record.data.locked && perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.delete")) {
        menu.add(new Ext.menu.Item({
            text: t('delete'),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_delete",
            handler: this.remove.bind(this, tree, record)
        }));
    }

    if (record.data.permissions.rename && record.data.id != 1 && !record.data.locked && perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.rename")) {
        menu.add(new Ext.menu.Item({
            text: t('rename'),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_key pimcore_icon_overlay_go",
            handler: this.editObjectKey.bind(this, tree, record)
        }));
    }


    // advanced menu
    var advancedMenuItems = [];
    var user = pimcore.globalmanager.get("user");

    if (record.data.permissions.create && perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.searchAndMove")) {
        advancedMenuItems.push({
            text: t('search_and_move'),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_search pimcore_icon_overlay_go",
            handler: this.searchAndMove.bind(this, tree, record)
        });
    }

    if (record.data.id != 1 && user.admin) {
        var lockMenu = [];
        if (record.data.lockOwner && perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.unlock")) { // add unlock
            lockMenu.push({
                text: t('unlock'),
                iconCls: "pimcore_icon_lock pimcore_icon_overlay_delete",
                handler: function () {
                    pimcore.elementservice.lockElement({
                        elementType: "object",
                        id: record.data.id,
                        mode: "null"
                    });
                }.bind(this)
            });
        } else {
            if (perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.lock")) {
                lockMenu.push({
                    text: t('lock'),
                    iconCls: "pimcore_icon_lock pimcore_icon_overlay_add",
                    handler: function () {
                        pimcore.elementservice.lockElement({
                            elementType: "object",
                            id: record.data.id,
                            mode: "self"
                        });
                    }.bind(this)
                });
            }

            if (perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.lockAndPropagate")) {
                lockMenu.push({
                    text: t('lock_and_propagate_to_childs'),
                    iconCls: "pimcore_icon_lock pimcore_icon_overlay_go",
                    handler: function () {
                        pimcore.elementservice.lockElement({
                            elementType: "object",
                            id: record.data.id,
                            mode: "propagate"
                        });
                    }.bind(this)
                });
            }
        }

        if(record.data.locked) {
            // add unlock and propagate to children functionality
            if (perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.unlockAndPropagate")) {
                lockMenu.push({
                    text: t('unlock_and_propagate_to_children'),
                    iconCls: "pimcore_icon_lock pimcore_icon_overlay_delete",
                    handler: function () {
                        pimcore.elementservice.unlockElement({
                            elementType: "object",
                            id: record.data.id
                        });
                    }.bind(this)
                });
            }
        }

        if (lockMenu.length > 0) {
            advancedMenuItems.push({
                text: t('lock'),
                iconCls: "pimcore_icon_lock",
                hideOnClick: false,
                menu: lockMenu
            });
        }
    }

    menu.add("-");

    if(advancedMenuItems.length) {
        menu.add({
            text: t('advanced'),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_more",
            hideOnClick: false,
            menu: advancedMenuItems
        });
    }

    if (perspectiveCfg.inTreeContextMenu("object.reload")) {
        menu.add({
            text: t('refresh'),
            iconCls: "pimcore_icon_reload",
            handler: this.reloadNode.bind(this, tree, record)
        });
    }

    pimcore.helpers.hideRedundantSeparators(menu);

    pimcore.plugin.broker.fireEvent("prepareObjectTreeContextMenu", menu, this, record);

    menu.showAt(e.pageX+1, e.pageY+1);
},
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. I tried in alternate way today by using users/roles permissions (save, publish, unpublish...) to the object , it worked.